# Obtener Int de Firebase

Tags: android, android-studio

Se como obtener un string, pero al querer obtener un int causa un error.

El campo que cree en firebase es de tipo Number, supongo que es el indicado para obtener un entero

```
db.collection("home").document("web").get().addOnSuccessListener {
            cant_scroll = it.get("cantscroll") as Int    //marca el error
        }
```

ERROR

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.space.victory, PID: 17522
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
        at com.space.victory.MainActivity$onCreate$3.onSuccess(MainActivity.kt:67)
        at com.space.victory.MainActivity$onCreate$3.onSuccess(MainActivity.kt:29)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8107)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Comment: El mensaje de error es bastante claro: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer` significa que el valor que hay en `cantscroll` es de tipo `Long` , no un entero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore almacena todos los numeros enteros como `Long`. Todo lo que necesitas hacer para convertirlo es agregar un `toInt()`

```
db.collection("home").document("web").get().addOnSuccessListener {
    cant_scroll = it.getLong("cantscroll").toInt()
}
```

Comment: Gracias, funciono.